# CWWKF1219E: The IBM WebSphere Liberty Repository cannot be reached

Tags: java, proxy, console, websphere-liberty

Downloaded and unpacked Websphere Liberty Profile wlp-javaee7-8.5.5.9.zip. I am behind a firewall and I was trying to install the adminCenter, but got the error:

> CWWKF1219E: The IBM WebSphere Liberty Repository cannot be reached. Verify that   your computer has network access and firewalls are configured correctly, then try the action again. If the connection still fails, the repository server might be temporarily unavailable.

To solve this I used information from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/http-proxy-setting-java-setting-proxy-java/.

Is there a better method to configure the access of various IBM utils to external repositories?

Comment: Is there a question here?  You said "To solve this I used info", which implies you solved the problem...

Comment: Completed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also set http proxy settings for `installUtility` by putting

```
proxyHost=my.proxy.server.ibm.com
proxyPort=9080
proxyUser=myname
proxyPassword={aes}AH5NLyd7DfGb12pK17Pw+
```

in your `${wlp.install.dir}/etc/repositories.properties` as described in the [Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_config_installutility.html)

Note that the password should be encoded with `securityUtility`